# Json(/hash) to ruby object?

Tags: javascript, ruby

In Javascript you can access json as objects.

```
person = {
  name: {
    first: "Peter",
    last: "Parker"
  }
}

person.name.first
```

In ruby I have to use it like this:

```
person[:name][:first]
```

Is it possible to access json (and hash) as an object just like in javascript?

Comment: I am still learning Ruby, but to get `person.name.first` to work in Ruby, these would need to be methods. You would probably need to override the `method_missing` in Hash to do a hash lookup when the property is not found.

Comment: @anurag. i wonder if there is a method that converts between json and ruby object smoothly.

Comment: Sure such a method can easily be written from what I understand, and most likely one would exist too. The main idea will be to dynamically add methods to the given hash instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out the Hashie gem.  It lets you do just what you are looking for.  It has a Mash class which takes JSON and XML parsed hashes and gives you object-like access.  It actually does deep-dives into the hash, converting any arrays or hashes inside the hash, etc.

http://github.com/intridea/hashie

Answer (score 1):

There is a json gem in ruby.  Perhaps that will help.

http://flori.github.com/json/

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses object attributes as its implementation of associative arrays. So, using Ruby's hash type is basically doing the same thing.

Comment: How do I access it like an object like in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Rails has built in support for encoding hashes as JSON and decoding JSON into a hash through ActiveSupport::JSON.  Using built-in support avoids the need for installing a gem.

```
For example:
hash = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("{ \"color\" : \"green\" }") 
  => {"color"=>"green"} 
hash["color"]
  => "green"
```

For more info, see:
http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/

Comment: That's not what he was asking for.